# Creating Compojure routes from a list

Tags: clojure, compojure

I've just been playing with Compojure recently, and I've got a small basic webapp.  For my HTML templates I'm using Enlive, and I've got a namespace that holds all the simple, static pages.  The defroute call for these pages looks like this:

```
(defroutes public-routes
  (GET "/" []
    (info/index-template))
  (GET "/about" []
    (info/about-template))
  (GET "/contact" []
    (info/contact-template)))
```

I've actually got a few more than that, but that should give the idea of what I'm doing.

Now, I thought, that's really just bunch of repetition on my part, so I thought I would try the following:

```
(defroutes info-routes
  (map #(GET (str "/" %) [] (ns-resolve 'webapp.pages.info
                                        (symbol (str % "-template"))))
       '("about" "contact")))
```

Of course, this doesn't work, as the map is returning a lazy sequence and not a body (?) of functions.
Does someone know what I need to do to get this idea to work?

Or should I be using a completely different approach to cut down on repeating myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always use the `routes` function which is used by defroutes:

```
(defroutes info-routes
  (apply routes
    (map #(GET (str "/" %) [] 
               (ns-resolve 'webapp.pages.info
                           (symbol (str % "-template"))))
         '("about" "contact"))))
```

But that's still quite boring, let's spice it up! ;-)

```
(defn templates-for [& nss]
  (->> nss
       (map ns-publics)
       (apply concat)
       (filter #(->> % first str
                     (re-seq #"-template$")))
       (map second)))

(defn template-uri [template]
  (->> template meta :name name
       (re-seq  #"(.*)-template$")
       first second (str "/")))

(defn template->route [template]
  (GET (template-uri template) [] template))

(defroutes public-routes
  (GET "/" [] "foo")
  (apply routes (map template->route
                     (templates-for 'webapp.pages.info))))
```

With this code, the `templates-for` function will look for any functions finishing with "-template" in the namespaces given and write the appropriate route with them. Look how I'm not using any macro, but plenty of composition.

Comment: I did have some problems, as an argument now gets passed in, where I wasn't passing one before, but I just fixed my defsnippet argument list to [_] and now it works perfectly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[`defroutes` is a macro](http://weavejester.github.com/compojure/compojure.core-api.html#compojure.core/defroutes) so unfortunately you wont be able to pass it to a function like map. You would need to write a macro that expanded into a call to defroutes. or look at the functions that it expands into and call them directly.

It wont work to create a list of routes within the call to defroutes like this

```
(defroutes public-routes
  (make-list-of-routes)
```

would expand into a list of routes:

```
(defroutes public-routes
  ( (GET "/" [] (info/index-template)) 
    (GET "/about" [] (info/about-template))
    (GET "/contact" [] (info/contact-template))) )
```

if `defroutes` where a normal function you would solve this with `apply`

```
(apply defroutes (conj 'public-routes (make-list-of-routes)))
```

because `defroutes` is a macro it is completely finished before apply could run and the results would not make a lot of sense. You really can't compose macroes as functions. macroes **are not first class citizens** in clojure (or any lisp i know of)
When some Clojurians (not usually me) say "Macroes are evil" they often think about situations like this where you run into the fact that something is a macro when you try to compose it and can't.

the solution is to not use the defroutes macro and call the routes function directly.

Comment: I'm not sure if I misunderstand, but I'm not passing a macro to map, I'm trying to get the result of a map passed to a macro.

To my understanding, my function is returning a lazy sequence of functions that I then want defroutes to handle.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: Following Arthur's advice we can discsover that `(defroutes r a b c)` is a shortcut for `(def r (routes a b c))`, where `routes` is (luckily!) an ordinary function.

Your example ends up as `(routes [a b c])` (with a seq instead of the vector, but you get the idea) instead of `(routes a b c)`. This can be fixed with apply: `(def r (apply routes [a b c]))`.

If `routes` would have been a macro, this of course wouldn't have worked.